# Open links from embedded google form in parent window

Tags: iframe

I can't seem to find an answer to this, since most answers assume you can include an {a href> tag.

I have a google form embedded into Wordpress for customers to submit details. It is embedded using and iframe using the share code from the google form itself.

On the confirmation page after the customer has submitted a response, we have a link for a customer to click to process an order, however this opens our own website again, within the iframe.

I want to open this in the parent window. Is it possible?

NB Google Forms appears to not let me mark up the link. If i put <a href="https://example.com>Click HERE{/a> - it just makes the https://example.com a link within the tag.